# Figure and its environment only appears when added in certain chapters or sections

Tags: floats, debugging

This is the weirdest behavior I have ever had.

The figure file is inside of a folder called "fig", which is set with `\graphicspath{{./fig/}}`. My document consists of a main .tex document that inputs multiple tex documents, one for each chapter.

I call it with:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figurefile}
    \caption{Random caption.}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

I'm trying to add this to a specific subsection inside of a section inside of a chapter. This works for every other figure in my work, except that for some reason it is not working on this exact section!

When I try to cut and paste the figure command to some other subsection in the same chapter it works, and when I try to add it where I want, the figure isn't added, the reference to it in the text disappears, and instead of the figure I have a weird triple quotation mark where the figure should be.

Does anyone knows how I can try to debug this?

Edit:

Even weirder, this works and makes two pictures:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figurefile}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figurefile}
    \caption{Random caption.}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well there is a brace missing at the end of the \label argument.

Comment: do not ignore error messages from TeX!

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a small typo when I removed the actual name of the label / figure file to post the question.  It isn't there in the actual command.

Moreover, it also doesn't work when I removed the `\centering` command, label and caption. Also, there is nothing about the figure in the logs :/